# Get specific words followed by and preceded by words

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I need to get some words based on some other words that come after and before that words!
suppose that I have a String:

```
not me and you but me and no you but me not
```

so that the output should be:

```
not me
and no
no you
me not
```

In simple words i want to get words with no and not comes after or before the specific words!
I am trying as:

```
String regex = "(?i)%s\\s+([\\S]+)\\s+([\\S]+)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(String.format(regex, Pattern.quote("no"))).matcher("not me and you but me and no you but me not");

while (m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Having homework with a collegue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34705814/1743880? It is unclear what you're asking. How this output should be obtained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A somewhat more complex solution might look like

```
public  void  getWords(){
    String str = "I have not used no  water but the water not used by me and no sea not but water no!";
    String[] words = str.split(" +|\t+|!");//split by space, tab and exclamation mark

    int currentPos = 0;
    int len = words.length;
    List<String> matchedWords = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        if("no".equals(words[i])||"not".equals(words[i])){
            if(currentPos!=i-1&&i-1>=0)//so we leave out duplicate words
                matchedWords.add(words[i-1]);
            if(i+1<len-1)
                matchedWords.add(words[i+1]);//
            currentPos = i+1;
        }
    }

    for(String s : matchedWords)
        System.out.println(s);

}
```

And the output

```
 have, used, water, water, used, and, sea, but, water,
```

I have used your original sentence, which you have changed in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

i think two regexes would pre appropriate? One selecting any word followed by no or not: `/\w+( no| not)/g` and one for selecting no or not followed by any word: `/(no |not )\w+/g`

Answer (score 0):

Try  following

```
(?<=no|not)\w+
```

this will match word after `no` or `not`

```
\w+(?=no|not)
```

this will match word after which `no` or `not` comes. 

 Now conjunction of this two is probably what you want.

```
(?<=no|not)\w+(?=no|not)
```